# Spring security for overlap URL range

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I don't know how to configure spring security to specify different ROLEs for overlaping URLs.

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/app/ws**" access="ROLE_WEBSERVICE"/>
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/app**" access="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
```

I need to accept user with role ROLE_WEBSERVICE on /app/ws** even if this user does not have user ROLE_ADMIN.

Could you point me to the correct place of documentation? I could not find it. Thanks.

Comment: And what isn't working? Currently one **must** have the ROLE_WEBSERVICE to access that URL. So I would expect it to work (a ROLE_ADMIN wouldn't be able to access it).

Comment: User with only ROLE_WEBSERVICE should be able to call webservices (this is not working). But webservices are accesible only for users who has BOTH roles (ROLE_ADMIN AND ROLE_WEBSERVICE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you switch to an expression rule instead of the vanilla `RoleVoter` you get more flexibility, e.g.

```
<http use-expressions="true">
    ...
    <intercept-url pattern="/app/ws**" access="hasRole('ROLE_WEBSERVICE') and hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/app**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    ...
```